# Firebase auth not receiving data from register/login screen android studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, mobile-application, android-app-signing

My login and signup screen working well on the android studio emulator but at the firebase auth console there is no data inserted. Although I have register and manage to login by the registered acc on the emulator . I don’t know where is the data stored since there are no data came in my firebase Auth console.

Comment: Show us the code that you are using and the security rules.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.